# Image src Attribute for div element

Tags: html, css, tags

I stumbled across [this post on seroundtable.com](https://www.seroundtable.com/google-images-div-tags-25885.html).  It says that images in `<div src=”/image.jpg”></div>` won’t get indexed by Google.

Now I am really confused because I can’t get an image displayed using this method and w3schools [doesn’t list src as an attribute](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_src.asp) which can be used in an div-element…

What's right now? Is it possible to display an image using `<div src="/image.jpg">` or did I get bamboozled by Barry Schwartz and John Müller?

Comment: div dosen't have a src attrribute, you need to set a css style to it

Comment: You got bamboozled

Answer (score 0):

```html
<div style="background-image: url(image.jpg); width: 300px; height:300px;"></div>
```

This method will cover the whole page that puts a picture on the "body" tag.